# Tensorflow: Crop largest central square region of image

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

My network takes images of size `100 x 100` pixels. Therefore I have to resize the images of my dataset which are of different size. I want to be able to extract the largest central square region from a given image and then resize it to `100 x 100`.

To be more precisely, let's say an image has a width of `200` pixels and a height of `50` pixels. Then I want to extract the largest central square region which is in this example `50 x 50` followed by resizing the image to `100 x 100` pixels.

What is the right way to do that using Tensorflow? Right now I am using `tf.image.resize_images()` which distorts the image and I want to get rid of that.

Comment: What is the shape of your tensors? That is, is it `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` or something else?

Comment: @jdehesa Every image is of shape `(width, height, channels)`. I can not present my dataset as `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` since `height` and `width` of each image can vary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [`crop_to_bounding_box`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_to_bounding_box) is doing what you need:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def crop_center(image):
    h, w = image.shape[-3], image.shape[-2]
    if h > w:
        cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, (h - w) // 2, 0, w, w)
    else:
        cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, 0, (w - h) // 2, h, h)
    return tf.image.resize_images(cropped_image, (100, 100))
```

Comment: Is there a solution where I do not have to provide any other information than the image? Your solution works only for images of size `200 x 50` right?

Comment: @Samuel Well, of course you have to plug in other numbers than 200 and 50 if your dimensions are different ;) I updated my answer. I'm not aware of any function doing exactly what you want in one step.

Comment: I can not get the correct shape, `image.shape` returns (None, None, 3). I am mapping this function into a `tf.data.Dataset`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def crop_center_and_resize(img, size):
    s = tf.shape(img)
    w, h = s[0], s[1]
    c = tf.minimum(w, h)
    w_start = (w - c) // 2
    h_start = (h - c) // 2
    center = img[w_start:w_start + c, h_start:h_start + c]
    return tf.image.resize_images(img, [size, size])

print(crop_center_and_resize(tf.zeros((80, 50, 3)), 100))
# Tensor("resize_images/Squeeze:0", shape=(100, 100, 3), dtype=float32)
```

There is also [`tf.image.crop_and_resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize), which can do both things in one go, but you have to use normalized image coordinates with that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def crop_center_and_resize(img, size):
    s = tf.shape(img)
    w, h = s[0], s[1]
    c = tf.minimum(w, h)
    wn, hn = h / c, w / c
    result = tf.image.crop_and_resize(tf.expand_dims(img, 0),
                                      [[(1 - wn) / 2, (1 - hn) / 2, wn, hn]],
                                      [0], [size, size])
    return tf.squeeze(result, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf


def central_square_crop(image):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    h, w = image.get_shape()[0].value, image.get_shape()[1].value                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    side = tf.minimum(h, w)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    begin_h = tf.maximum(0, h - side) // 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    begin_w = tf.maximum(0, w - side) // 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    return tf.slice(image, [begin_h, begin_w, 0], [side, side, -1])                                                                                                                                                                                                   


def main():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    image_t = tf.reshape(tf.range(5 * 7), [5, 7])                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    image_t = tf.transpose(tf.stack([image_t, image_t, image_t]), [1, 2, 0])                                                                                                                                                                                          
    cropped_image_t = central_square_crop(image_t)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    with tf.Session() as sess:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        image, cropped_image = sess.run([image_t, cropped_image_t])                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        print(image[:, :, 0])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        print(cropped_image[:, :, 0])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    main()
```

Output before crop:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]]
```

After crop:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 8  9 10 11 12]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [22 23 24 25 26]
 [29 30 31 32 33]]
```

Then, apply resizing as usual.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

data_root_orig = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    origin="https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz",
    fname="flower_photos",
    untar=True,
)
data_root = pathlib.Path(data_root_orig)
print(data_root)
for item in data_root.iterdir():
    print(item)

import random

all_image_paths = list(data_root.glob("*/*"))
all_image_paths = [str(path) for path in all_image_paths]
image_count = len(all_image_paths)
print(image_count)

def preprocess_image(img: tf.Tensor):
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    shapes = tf.shape(img)
    h, w = shapes[-3], shapes[-2]
    small = tf.minimum(h, w)
    img = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(img, small, small)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [192, 192])
    img /= 255.0
    return img

@tf.function
def load_and_preprocess_image(path: str):
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    return preprocess_image(image)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_path = all_image_paths[0]
plt.imshow(load_and_preprocess_image(image_path))
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

orignal
[image: original]
resized
[[image: output image2]

Comment: What does `@tf.function` stand for? Where do you use the `random` module? What did the input image look like?

Comment: random is for augumentation. you can remove it. @tf.function is for compile the function into tensorflow's byte code.