# Tensorflow cannot get `image.shape` from method in `dataset.map( mapFn )`

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to do the `tensorflow` equivalent of `torch.transforms.Resize(TRAIN_IMAGE_SIZE)`, which resizes the **smallest** image dimension to `TRAIN_IMAGE_SIZE`. Something like this

```
def transforms(filename):
  parts = tf.strings.split(filename, '/')
  label = parts[-2]

  image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

  # this doesn't work with Dataset.map() because image.shape=(None,None,3) from Dataset.map()
  image = largest_sq_crop(image) 

  image = tf.image.resize(image, (256,256))
  return image, label

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('{}/*/*'.format(DATASET_PATH))
images_ds = list_ds.map(transforms).batch(4)
```

The simple answer is here: [Tensorflow: Crop largest central square region of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865717/tensorflow-crop-largest-central-square-region-of-image)

But when I use the method with `tf.data.Dataset.map(transforms)`, I get `shape=(None,None,3)` from inside `largest_sq_crop(image)`. The method works fine when I call it normally.

Comment: I believe the problem has to do with the fact that `EagerTensors` are not available within `Dataset.map()` so the shape is unknown. is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you include the definition of `largest_sq_crop`?

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer. It had to do with the fact that my resize method worked fine with eager execution, e.g. `tf.executing_eagerly()==True` but failed when used within `dataset.map()`.  Apparently, in that execution environment, `tf.executing_eagerly()==False`.

My error was in the way I was unpacking the shape of the image to get dimensions for scaling. Tensorflow graph execution does not seem to support access to the `tensor.shape` tuple.

```
  # wrong
  b,h,w,c = img.shape
  print("ERR> ", h,w,c)
  # ERR>  None None 3

  # also wrong
  b = img.shape[0]
  h = img.shape[1]
  w = img.shape[2]
  c = img.shape[3]
  print("ERR> ", h,w,c)
  # ERR>  None None 3

  # but this works!!!
  shape = tf.shape(img)
  b = shape[0]
  h = shape[1]
  w = shape[2]
  c = shape[3]
  img = tf.reshape( img, (-1,h,w,c))
  print("OK> ", h,w,c)
  # OK>  Tensor("strided_slice_2:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) Tensor("strided_slice_3:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) Tensor("strided_slice_4:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

I was using shape dimensions downstream in my `dataset.map()` function and it threw the following exception because it was getting `None` instead of a value.

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (-1, None, None, 3). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

When I switched to manually unpacking the shape from `tf.shape()`, everything worked fine.

Comment: Think this only works with a batch size of 1? `ValueError: slice index 3 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice_3}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice_3/stack, strided_slice_3/stack_1, strided_slice_3/stack_2)' with input shapes: [3], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <3>, input[2] = <4>, input[3] = <1>`